# accept_nested_attributes is not destroying the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, has-many, fields-for

My problem is related to the accept_nested_attributes , I have a model name `StudentProfile` and it contain the following code:

```
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :projects_attributes
   has_many :projects ,:inverse_of => :student_profile,:dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
end
```

My another model contain the following code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student_profile
end
```

and My view File contain the following code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :projects do |builder| %>
   <%= render "projects_fields", :f => builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Project", f, :projects %>
```

Now the problem is whenever i save a student profile i can actually save the record of project as well but whenever i try to update the student profile and removing one of the project, it is not actually destroying the project on update but my `params` include the following content:

```
"projects_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"test", "_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}}
```

Please clarify me what i have done wrong.

Comment: can you post view code?

Comment: i already have posted in my question

Answer (score 1):

It may be a mass attribute protection, on your StudentProfile, add the following:

```
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :projects_attributes

  has_many :projects ,:inverse_of => :student_profile,:dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
end
```

Comment: Added in my model but the problem still persist

Comment: I know its a silly question, but did you restarted the server? Your log looks fine, the form is sending the right parameters, unless there is something really weird in your controllers, it seems like a mass attribute issue.

Comment: so what was the solution? answer your own question so its here in stackoverflow in case someone else run into the same problem and its not related to mass attributes